# How to give a timer to a windows command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

How can you give ***ANY*** windows command a timer before canceling/force exiting/terminating the command?

I have done a lot of searching on the internet and came across:
waitfor, timeout, sleep, etc, but none have helped.

Lets say I have a huge file, and from the windows command prompt and I am catting it out:

```
..../Desktop> cat hugefile.txt
```

But if it doesn't finish in say 5 seconds, to stop it?

Could look like:

```
..../Desktop> timer(cat hugefile.txt) 5
```

or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:: start calling cat
start "somewindowtitle" pusspusspuss
timeout /t 5 >nul
for /f "skip=2tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq somewindowtitle"') do echo(taskkill /pid %%a
```

should get you going. Required command merely `echo`ed.